# Multiple SELECT in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I want to get a particular value from 3 different tables. Each table has the same structure but contains data for a different period of a year.

```
Temp_Table_Jun (Contains data for June month)
---------------
CustNo    CustName  Revenue
1000      John      5.55
```

Similary I have two more tables

- Temp_table_Apr
- Temp_table_May

Now I run a query

```
select sum(Revenue)Rev_June from Temp_Table_Jun where CustNo='1000'
```

to get the results for June. Now my problem is I want to get the revenue details for all the month in a single query.

I need something like,(THIS IS WRONG AND DOESN'T WORK)

```
select Rev_June,Rev_Apr,Rev_May,((Rev_June+Rev_Apr+Rev_May)/3)Avg_3_Mon from 
(
        select sum(Revenue)Rev_June from Temp_Table_Jun where CustNo='1000',
        select sum(Revenue)Rev_Apr from Temp_Table_Apr where CustNo='1000',
        select sum(Revenue)Rev_May from Temp_Table_May where CustNo='1000'   

)
```

How can this be achieved? I am using Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the data you can do it the following way. Oracle 10g does not have a `PIVOT` but you can use `CASE` statements to replicate the functionality:

```
SELECT sum(case when month = 'June' then Rev END) June
  , sum(case when month = 'May' then Rev END) May
  , sum(case when month = 'April' then Rev END) April
  , avg(Rev) as Average
FROM
(
  SELECT sum(revenue) Rev, 'June' as Month from rev_june where cust_no = '1000'
  union all
  SELECT sum(revenue) Rev, 'April' from rev_apr where cust_no = '1000'
  union all
  SELECT sum(revenue) Rev, 'May' from rev_may where cust_no = '1000'
) x
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e6422/16)

Or you can do the following:

```
SELECT June, April, May, (June + April + May)/3 as Average
FROM
(
  select 
    (SELECT sum(revenue) from rev_june where cust_no = '1000') as June
  , (SELECT sum(revenue) from rev_apr where cust_no = '1000') as April
  , (SELECT sum(revenue) from rev_may where cust_no = '1000') as May
  from dual
) x
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e6422/17)

Comment: +1, and `avg(Rev)` would do as well as `sum(Rev)/count(rev)`.

Comment: @bluefeet Great answer bluefeet - I couldn't think how to do that pivot from rows to columns

Answer (score 3):

The following might work:

```
select Rev_June, Rev_Apr, Rev_May,
    (Rev_June + Rev_Apr + Rev_May) / 3 Avg_3_Mon
from (
    (select sum(Revenue) from Temp_Table_Jun where CustNo='1000') as Rev_June,
    (select sum(Revenue) from Temp_Table_Apr where CustNo='1000') as Rev_Apr,
    (select sum(Revenue) from Temp_Table_May where CustNo='1000') as Rev_May
    from dual
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it works in Oracle 10g, but a UNION query roughly like the following would normally work in databases I've worked with:

```
select sum(Revenue) Rev_June from Temp_Table_Jun where CustNo='1000'
UNION
select sum(Revenue) Rev_Apr from Temp_Table_Apr where CustNo='1000'
UNION
select sum(Revenue) Rev_May from Temp_Table_May where CustNo='1000'
```

I'm not crysal clear about punctuation - do you need a semi-colon at the end etc? - but that might get you started.

I think I would do it slightly differently because each query must have the same structure for a UNION query to work:

```
select sum(Revenue) Revenue_Sum, 'Jun' Month from Temp_Table_Jun where CustNo='1000'
UNION
select sum(Revenue) Revenue_Sum, 'Apr' Month from Temp_Table_Apr where CustNo='1000'
UNION
select sum(Revenue) Revenue_Sum, 'May' Month from Temp_Table_May where CustNo='1000'
```

Now, that doesn't quite get the average sum and the 3 columns you're looking for, but perhaps you could create a VIEW with something like this UNION query and then use a GROUP BY query on that VIEW to aggregate the data.

Comment: You want UNION ALL instead of UNION. UNION can be costly because it identifies and eliminates all duplicates.

Comment: Hi David, I need the results in different columns but with the above query I get them in the same columns. Can anything be done on it?

Comment: @Niranjan I tried a few ideas on SQL Fiddle but could only turn the rows into something like an array in one field, not separate columns. I think you're going to get better results from bluefeet's `CASE` approach.